# Need help installing open source software from github to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, github

I'm trying to install open source software from github to Heroku using Ruby on Rails.  This is for a community project.  I have no idea what I'm doing, but I'm trying to figure it out as I go.  I'm not a developer.  At all.

I ran this command successfully: git clone git://github.com/austintimeexchange/oscurrency

Then I changed to the oscurrency directory and ran this command: rake heroku:install

I was told I was missing the Rails 2.3.11 gem, so I followed the instructions to install it.

Now, when I run rake heroku:install, I get this error: rake/rdoctask is obsolete and no longer supported.

I have no idea what this means or how to go forward from here. I'm concerned that installing the gem was the wrong choice. Can anyone help guide me through this?  My understanding is that this is a simple install, but with no experience and no detailed instructions, it's not so simple for me.  Thanks!

```
         Lynn
```

@Anil Ok, I cloned the correct version this time and ran bundle install. After much installing, it gave this error:

Failed to build gem native extension.
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
No source for ruby-1.9.3-p392 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem
extconf.rb failed
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably due to lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need more configuration options.

It then listed the provided configuration options and said where the Gem files would remain installed for inspection and where the results were logged to.  I can include this if needed, but I'm wondering if there's some way to copy it instead of typing it all out?

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Thanks for your help!  I've at least made progress!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you cloned a 3 year old repository , which is outdated by now .

Clone this repository https://github.com/oscurrency/oscurrency , then first run

```
bundle install
```

and then install heroku and other stuff.

Comment: Thank you!  I was using instructions written in 2010, so no wonder I had an old file.  Duh.